# How to let group of developers access the same sharepoint site and develop on it together?

Tags: html, asp.net, css, sql, web

I am new to sharepoint ..

I am now implementing a workflow web-based system using sharepoint with a group of developers who will develop with me..

My question is: how Can I give a permission for my group members to access my sharepoint site and develop in it ??

Comment: what you want to do with the permission? do u means source control like team foundation server? source safe and so on?

Comment: I mean that they can access the site, develop a web pages in sharepoint designer and publish them to the server, and so on.           

I don't know if that possible? or just only one developer can edit the site??

Answer (score 0):

On my setup I just go to Site Actions in the top left, then "Site Permissions".